# How to use regex in the following query?

Tags: mysql, regex

There is a column in my DB where data is stored like:

```
/accounts/2/xyz/a
/accounts/2/xyz/b
/accounts/3/xyz/a
/accounts/3/xyz/b
/accounts/5/xyz/a
/accounts/5/xyz/b
```

Now, I have list of selected accounts let's say account_id=[2,5]. I want to fetch data for the following keys `/accounts/<acount_id>/xyz/a`
So, what will be the optimal query for fetching such data? For now, I am generating keys for the selected account_id list and firing query over that but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * FROM  tbl where accountNumber like '/accounts/%/xyz/a'
```

refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: First of all * doesn't work with LIKE and I am not looking for generic pattern matching. I am looking for optimal matching for following keys only:
/accounts/<from already selected account id>/xyz/a